# html to pdf convert when send mail

Tags: codeigniter

How to convert a HTML file to PDF in CODEIGNITER when sending a mail?

```
$this->load->library('html2pdf');

$this->html2pdf->folder('./assets/pdfs/');
$this->html2pdf->filename('email_test.pdf');
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');

$data = array(
    'title' => 'PDF Created',
    'message' => 'Hello World!'
);
//Load html view
$this->html2pdf->html($this->load->view('pdf', $data, true));

//Check that the PDF was created before we send it
$path = $this->html2pdf->create('save');
```

I use this code for converting.

Comment: whats error u r getting?

Comment: " Unable to load the requested class: Html2pdf ". But I Put html2pdf File in Libraries Folder

Comment: filename mismatch , make sure file name and class name are same

Comment: Can you please tell me this code is right or not ? I check file name and class name are same.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can you try with TCPDF, that always worked for me :) [TCPDF INTEGRATION CI](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/TCPDF-Integration)

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the link to your answer via quotation. Posting link-only answers is susceptible to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).